# how to set pandas dataframe multiindex in constructor

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

After preparing the data

```
import pandas as pd

_indexcols = ['key1', 'key2']
_columns = ['key1', 'key2', 'data1', 'data2']

_data = []
_data.append(['k11', 'k12', 'd11', 'd12'])
_data.append(['k21', 'k22', 'd21', 'd22'])
```

I can do this

```
_df = pd.DataFrame(_data, columns=_columns)
_df = _df.set_index(keys=_indexcols)
```

But not this.

```
_df = pd.DataFrame(_data, columns=_columns, index=_indexcols)
```

Why?

How do I define the indexcols so that they are accepted immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataframe constructor creates index first and assigns the data second. So you can't access the data earlier to assign it to index.

But if you are looking for the approach using only constructor and dont want set_index you can make use of `numpy` and `pd.MultiIndex`

```
temp = np.array(_data)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(temp[:,:2])
_df = pd.DataFrame(temp[:,2:],columns=_columns[2:],index =idx)
```

```
        data1 data2
k11 k21   d11   d12
k12 k22   d21   d22
```